# how to display current section title in header

Tags: header-footer

how to display current section title in header insted of chapter title?

I'm using `book` and `fancychap`

MWE

```
\documentclass [11pt,oneside,final]{book}
\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[font={footnotesize,it}]{caption}
\usepackage{bookman} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[left=35mm,top=30mm,right=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{cp1256}
\setcode{cp1256}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{array}

\setarab
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
\chapter{introduction} \thispagestyle{empty}

\section{one}
bla bla bla bla bla

\section{two}
bla bla bla bla 

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

- `\pagestyle{fancy}` sets the page style to the style delivered and editable with `fancyhdr`.
- `\fancyhf{}` sets all head and foot elements empty.
- `\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}` sets the left head element  to `\rightmark`, which contains the current section (`\leftmark` is the current chapter).
- `\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}` sets the right head element  to the page number.
- `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` lets the head rule disappear.

Possible selectors for the optional argument of `\fancyhead`/`\fancyfoot` are `L` (left), `C` (center) or `R` (right) for the position of the element and `E` (even) or `O` (odd) to distinguish even and odd pages. If you omit `E`/`O` the element is set for all pages.

Comment: i have applied this solution. the problem it put the section title on the right side of the page with underline and i need it in the left without underline . Also it move the page number from top right of page to the end of the page and i need it to stay at top right.

Comment: @user1200219. You didn’t say that ;-) I change my example, but you could have find the solution yourself by reading the manual ;-) …

Comment: it is fine now. but the page number need to be in in most right if it can because it is in some how near to middle? also, is it possible to include subsection too not just section ?

Comment: The page number is exactly flushed right with the text – sorry I don’t understand where you want it to be … In `scrpage2` you can use `\automark{subsection}` but I don’t know something similar for `fancyhdr`.

Comment: how to fix this warning Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 13.59999pt.

Comment: Just do what the warning suggest: increase the head height, e.g. with `geometry`.

Comment: This did not give me section titles, only section numbers.

Answer (score 16):

### Updated Answer

Please use `scrlayer-scrpage` instead …

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Except for `\clearscrheadfoot{}` which is replaced by `\clearpairofpagestyles` nothing has changed for the user.

*You may also like to read further in my german blog: [TeX-Beispiel des Monats „Layout II: Kopf- und Fußzeilen“](http://tobiw.de/tbdm/layout-2).*

---

### Original Answer

You can use [`scrpage2` from KOMA-Script bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot{}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

- `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` sets the page style to the style delivered and editable with `scrpage2`.
- `\clearscrheadfoot{}` sets all head and foot elements empty.
- `\ohead{\rightmark}` sets the outer head element (`o`) to `\rightmark`, which contains the current section (`\leftmark` is the current chapter).
- `\cfoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` sets the page number to the center foot element (`c`). The optimal argument defines the `plain` style (used on chapter starting pages).

This image shows all possible elements.

[image: scrpage2 head/foot elements]
<sup>source: `scrguien.pdf`, p. 198</sup>

Comment: Notes: 1) In one-sided documents (as in `scrartcl` by default) there are only right/odd pages, so only commands seen on the right side of the image are applied. 2) From KOMA-Script, version 3.12, on there’s a successor package named `scrlayer-scrpage`, that is as far as I see downwards compatible to `scrpage2`.

Comment: @Speravir: Thanks for the notes :-) I’m aware of the new package but didn’t had the time yet to inspect it :-)

Comment: Trying this solution had absolutely no effect on my article. Perhaps it's only for books?

Comment: The difference between books and articles is, that the latter are single-paged by default and books in double pages, which means that an article makes no difference between even and odd pages. For an article all pages are considers right/odd.

Answer (score 1):

I would use labels at the sections and reference them with `\nameref{}`. At every new section I think you must redefine your header with the new one...

Comment: I’d say it’s preferable to use the automatics LaTeX provides ;-)

Comment: The other way I don't know till now. But your the solution is very nice and much more nice than my :)

Comment: The `\nameref` mechanism is useful to but more for references and not of automating head/foot elements … :-)