# How to set different headers for a specific pages in one document?

Tags: header-footer, thesis

I have thesis template in latex which have pages in the beginning to setup the layout of the thesis. For example I have contents, list of table, list of figure, Notation and Acronyms. The first page of each content appears with the heading, and the other pages present the header for each type of content except Notation and Acronyms the second page of those contents appears with the header of "list of table". Can you help me please and thank you in advance.

Comment: \thispagestyle{...style name...} tags helps you to change the headers for a particular page alone...

Comment: I understand that your problem is not that there is nothing in the head line of the pages, but that your sections have the header "Notation" and "Acronyms", respectively, but the head line of the pages still reads "List of table", right?

Comment: Yes this right and all the header in the thesis is correct just the second page of the  "Notation" and "Acronyms".

Comment: So what I should do and when can I make the change?

Comment: Yes this right Tiuri and all the header in the thesis is correct just the second page of the  "Notation" and "Acronyms".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your thesis template, you might be able to explicitly set the header by using

`\markboth{Acronyms}{Acronyms}`

and

`\markboth{Notation}{Notation}`

at the start of the respective sections.

At least, it worked for me when I had the same problem.

Comment: Thank you very much Inquisitive Lurker it is work with me also.

Answer (score 0):

please check [fancyhdr](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) package. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{section title}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

The answer was previously provided in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151784/how-to-display-current-section-title-in-header).