# Problem getting the section name as header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr

I am currently writing a PhD. I have the following code

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

which I obtained from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151784/how-to-display-current-section-title-in-header). My goal is to have the section name instead of the chapter name in  the top left part of each page the thesis, but I am getting the chapter name instead. Does anybody know if this might be caused by a conflict between packages?

The ones I am using are:

```
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{vector} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{subeqnarray}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{srcltx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{graphicx,subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}   
\usepackage{psfrag}       
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigmat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

I have also proved the example:

```
\documentclass{book}
    
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\section{AAAA}

\lipsum[1-20]


\section{BBBB}

\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

and it works as intended.

Any help is appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: Can you create a MWE which does *not* work as expected? If I add all your packages to the preamble of your current MWE (except `vector` which seems to be not supported in overleaf, but I don't think it is responsible for this), it still works as expected for me.

Comment: I don't think I can, each time I am more convinced that it has to do with the template, but I am not profficient enough in latex to solve it. Thanks anyway