Display the current section in header
For some reason I have troubles displaying the current section in a header. Here;s what I do^
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section One}
    \subsection{SubSection One}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{SubSection Two}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Section Two}
    \subsection{SubSection One}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{SubSection Two}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}

and it gives me this:

What do I do wrong?

Are you looking for \fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}?

Can you clarify on which side you want to have the section title and if you want to have the subsection title on the other side?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, I want to have a section title on the right side of the header. I read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151784/how-to-display-current-section-title-in-header that rightmark is the one to go, but for some reason it doesn't work

The example you link to uses chapters and sections, whereas you use sections and subsections. The higher ranking one is normally stored in leftmark, the lower ranking one in rightmark. So you need \leftmark

Normally, \leftmark will contain the higher ranking sectioning heading and \rightmark the lower ranking one. If you want to show the higher ranking one (section in your case), you should use \leftmark:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section One}
    \subsection{SubSection One}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{SubSection Two}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Section Two}
    \subsection{SubSection One}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \subsection{SubSection Two}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}


Edit: Sorry, wrong answer. Thanks @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz
new Answer: I guess \fancyhead[R]{\leftmark} will do it

Wont this just print the subsection title two times?

Thanks for the hint. I revised my answer.

Hey, unfortunately it doen't work in my case: when I add table of contents this command only puts the name of my ToC every time
